# 'Ì' or '\0' in visual studio is null

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

i write a code in visual studio and in algorithm seem to be right but 
but won't work! I don't know put `Ì` (-52) or `\0` for my code

```
void strcat(char *destin, char *source){
    while (*destin != '\0')
        destin++;
    while (*source != '\0')
    {
        *destin = *source;
        destin++;
        source++;
    }
    *destin = '\0';
}

main(){
    char s1[100];
    strcat(s1, "salam");
    strcat(s1, "hello");
    strcat(s1, "ahlan");
    strcat(s1, "keifolhal");
    printf("%s", s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Char '\0' is correct for a standard char sting. I don'yt understand what's your problem..

Comment: `char s1[100];` --> `char s1[100]="";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place the terminating zero in the source array. Write

```
char s1[100];
s1[0] = '\0';
```

or

```
char s1[100] = { '\0' };
```

or

```
char s1[100] = "";
```

or

```
char s1[100] = { "" };
```

The last three declarations are equivalent.

The function itself can be written the following way

```
char * strcat( char *destin, const char *source )
{
    char *p = destin;

    while ( *p != '\0' ) p++;
    while ( *p++ = *source++ );

    return destin;
}
```

Comment: Or just replace the 1st `strcat()` by `strcpy()`.